# Set Windows 7 resolution without monitor attached

Tags: windows, jenkins, screen-resolution

I have a Windows 7 Jenkins slave that reboots before some UI Tests.
But there is no monitor connected to the PC, so the resolution is too small for the UI tests to work.
Is there a way to set a fix resolution, that is always used when no monitor is connected?

Comment: Look at this post on super user which details out a registry way of fixing this issue. https://superuser.com/questions/604026/how-to-set-default-screen-resolution-and-color-depth-without-monitor-in-windows

Comment: I already tried this one, unfortunately it did not work.